# Controlling the 'levels' of differentiation in SageMath 9.1

Tags: sage, derivative

Sage seems to want to evaluate derivatives as far as possible using the chain rule.  A simple example is:

```
var('theta')
f = function('f')(theta)
g = function('g')(theta)

h = f*g
diff(h,theta)
```

which would display

```
g(theta)*diff(f(theta), theta) + f(theta)*diff(g(theta), theta)
```

My question is, is there a way to control just how far Sage will take derivatives?  In the example above for instance, how would I get Sage to display instead:

```
diff(f(theta)*g(theta))
```

I'm working through some pretty intensive derivations in fluid mechanics, and being able to not evaluate derivatives all the way like discussed above would really help with this.  Thanks in advance.  Would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

This would be called "holding" the derivative.

Adding this possibility to Sage has already been considered.

Progress on this is tracked at:

- [Sage Trac ticket 24861](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/24861)

and the ticket even links to a branch with code implementing this.

Although progress on this is stalled, and the branch has not been merged,
you could use the code from the branch.